# Electrical Motors

Tags: dc-motor, wheel

We are using 24 V brushed DC motor(total 2 pieces) and VNH5019 motor driver for voiced controllable smart wheelchair. Although 2 wheels are sourced by same voltage and current; one of them fall behind, always. Difference of velocity is not constant so we couldn't find any rate. What can we do? Have you an idea?

Comment: Swap the components around and see which the lessened performance goes with, then decide if it is in spec or faulty.  But if it looks like this sort of mismatch is going to be an ongoing problem, then be glad it showed up early in your design process and put encoders (or even old style tachometers) on the shafts and use a control loop to servo the actual speed to a commanded speed.  And put some thought into how this thing is going to stop safely when the voice detection gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the app requirements, but my guess is tha brushless motors shout be driven by a single two-axes controller. Then the speed will be accurately matched, because both motors have save position feedback (like hall effect sensors).

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be many things that make many small differences. Both inside the motor and outside.
All these small differences can incidentally sometimes cancel each other out, but most times they will add up to make the performance curve of the total power train off by 2%, 5%, 10% or even 20%.

As pointed out in the comments by Chris, if this is a production design you need to apply some sensoring and feedback control to it, any way that fits your design budget.

If it's a one-off you could try tuning the current division by adding small hindrances (20miliOhm, a small inductance, etc) in the path of the fast one, but they will always still be a victim of circumstance. If the person is leaning more to the right, the right motor will have a tougher job, if they are leaning more to the left, the left one will have the hard job.
If both are supplied the same control signal, the one with the harder job will always lag behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the motors in series? it is geberally done. It even helps while turning the chair. vtingole